# Improving memory efficiency of factory pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, prototype, factory

The simplicity and flexibility of JavaScript's concept of an "object" (really a map) has always appealed to me. For that reason, I prefer to completely avoid the concept of "object prototypes" (and "classes" which are simply syntactic sugar for object prototypes) and opt for a factory pattern instead.

I came across this article, stating that object prototypes conserve memory in comparison to the factory pattern: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/class-vs-factory-function-exploring-the-way-forward-73258b6a8d15

> "All methods will be created only once in the prototype object and shared by all instances"

Assume I have a web page which calls the following function lots of times to "instantiate" many AnglePointer objects:

```
var AnglePointer = function() {
    var privateMembers = {};
    privateMembers.angle = 0;

    var self = {};

    self.turn = function(degrees) {
        privateMembers.angle += degrees;
        while (privateMembers.angle > 359) {
            privateMembers.angle -= 360;
        }
        while (privateMembers.angle < 0) {
            privateMembers.angle += 360;
        }
    };

    return self;
};
```

Can I improve the memory efficiency by introducing a "shared" object like the following?

```
var AnglePointer = (function() {
    var sharedMembers = {};

    sharedMembers.turn = function(self, privateMembers, degrees) {
        privateMembers.angle += degrees;
        while (privateMembers.angle > 359) {
            privateMembers.angle -= 360;
        }
        while (privateMembers.angle < 0) {
            privateMembers.angle += 360;
        }
    };

    return function() {
        var privateMembers = {};
        privateMembers.angle = 0;

        var self = {};

        self.turn = function(degrees) {
            shared.turn(self, privateMembers, degrees);
        };

        return self;
    };
})();
```

In the second version, the implementation of the `turn` function is inside the `sharedMembers` object, leaving each "instance" of AnglePointer with just a small one-line function calling the shared function. Will this accomplish memory efficiency similar to that of an object prototype? Or will each instance's `turn` function take up just as much memory as before despite being a one-line function? If the latter, how do object prototypes avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with just a small one-line function calling the shared function

That is based on the missbelief that a new function will be created for every object. That is wrong. All functions in your code are parsed just once and only exist once. What gets created on every creation is a new closure (the spec calls it EnvironmentRecord). If the function foes not access any outer variables, this closure can be optimized away making it way more memory efficient (and probably faster).

Therefore your "new pattern" makes things actually worse (but just a bit). The main problem stays:

```
self.turn = function(degrees) {
   shared.turn(self, privateMembers, degrees);
};
```

That can't be optimized away, as the function uses variables from its parent's scope, and therefore a closure has to be created. Therefore there has to be a closure for every `turn` method, and every object has to keep a reference to its own closured `turn`.

Private members can be implemented quite accurately with Symbols:

```
const angle = Symbol.for("angle");

function AnglePointer() {
  return {
   [angle]: 0,
   turn(degrees) {
     this[angle] = (this[angle] + degrees) % 360;
   },
  };
}
```

Here the `turn` can hopefully be shared as it does not access any outer variables.

Comment: Do you have any insight as to how this problem is avoided in object prototypes? Given an instance of an object prototype, how does the instance call the shared function and pass along its own internal state without wrapping it in another function?

Comment: @circuitScholar using the prototype there is just one closure (or none at all). Think of `this` being an implicit argument, you could just do `function turn(this, degrees) { /*...*/ }` and call it as `turn(someInstance, 90)`

Comment: This is very interesting, it is often asked what exactly the new keyword does in JavaScript, and I have never seen this mentioned-- Passing this as an implicit argument to any functions defined in the object. So interestingly, a (tedious) way to solve this would be to write this responsibility into your code explicitly. AnglePointer could have its turn function defined like `turn(anglePointerInstance, degrees)` and any time some outer code instantiates AnglePointer and needs to turn it, it would be something like `myInstance = AnglePointer(); myInstance.turn(myInstance, 45);`